# Why mysql " where not exist " perform way much better than "not in" in this case? What is the mechanism of "where not exists"?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, relational-algebra

Recently, a result of a query operation really draws my attention.
Here it is: 
My 1st query is:

```
select * from tableA as a
where a.keyword NOT IN
(
select keyword from tableB
union
select keyword from tableC
union
select keyword from tableD
)
```

my second query is:

```
select * from tableA as a
where NOT EXISTS
(select NULL from
  (
  select keyword from tableB
  union
  select keyword from tableC
  union
  select keyword from tableD
  ) as t
where a.keyword=t.keyword
)
```

It is obvious that these two queries are equivalent. However the first one will take about 10 seconds to finish, the second only needs about 1 second. I really would like to know what mechanism leads to such a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

They are equal in terms they return the same result but technically optimizer may choose different paths to execute the query. It differs from engine to engine, according to statistics and things like that, but especially for mysql it's usually pretty straightforward and follows what you wrote in the query.

So the first will probably take everything from `tableB`, `tableC`, `tableD`, builds a hash from `keyword` and then executes the outer query and checks whether `keyword` exists in subquery.

The second will probably take each row from `tableA` and then will check if specific `keyword` exists in one of the tables `tableB`, `tableC`, `tableD`.

It may however change when you upgrade from one version to another and optimizer becomes smarter or significantly change number of rows in one of the tables etc.